# Como fazer input de senha com letras e números (Python)

Tags: python

Como faço para declarar uma variável de senha, onde a senha digitada deve ser obrigatoriamente com letras e números e com quantidade mínima de caracteres? (em Python)

A parte do código que já fiz:

```
while True:
    senha = input('Digite uma senha de fácil memorização: ')

    qtde_carac_senha = len(senha)

    if qtde_carac_senha < 8:
        print('Senha inválida. Escolha uma senha que tenha no mínimo 8 caracteres.')
    else:
        print('Senha cadastrada com sucesso.')
        break
```

Comment: Daniel, seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Acredito que vale de aprendizado pesquisar sobre Expressões Regulares (não precisa ser necessariamente em Python). Se quiser, pode começar por [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Você pode criar um set() com os tipos de caracteres esperados e usar any com um for para checar caractere por caractere da variavel `senha`, verificando assim se o valor esta dentro do set(). O de quantidade minima você já fez, que é o `< 8`.

Comment: Se for mesmo usar regex, tem alguns links [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8686/112052) (na seção "Senhas"). Mas acho que o mais simples é fazer um loop e verificar cada caractere mesmo...

Comment: @hkotsubo ou pode fazer um set() e checar os caracteres, como sendo os "aceitáveis" e "navegar" pela string (caractere por caractere), como citei antes, assim dessa forma pode até aproveitar a ideia para criar tipos de niveis de senha toleráveis e se aumentar a complexidade pode trocar o set() por outra coisa que contenha uma "especificação" de coisas como "minimo do tipo de caractere X". Claro q concordo q um regex "rápido" para resolver uma regrinha simples já é mais pratico, mas desenvolver talvez a "ideia" (sem regex) ajuda até a evoluir no entendimento de escrever uma "lógica" :)

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira bastante simples seria iterando caractere por caractere, alimentando contadores e depois lançar os erros de acordo com as contagens. Exemplo:

```
senha = input("Insira a senha:")

# contadores
count_alpha = 0
count_nums = 0

# checagem de caracteres
for c in senha:
    if c.isalpha():
        count_alpha += 1
    elif c.isdigit():
        count_nums += 1

# validações
erros = []

if len(senha) < 8:
    erros.append("Senha deve conter pelo menos 8 caracteres!")

if not count_alpha:
    erros.append("Senha deve conter letras!")

if not count_nums:
    erros.append("Senha deve conter números!")

# conclusão
if erros:
    print("Erros de senha:")
    for e in erros:
        print("-", e)
else:
    print("Senha OK")
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://replit.com/@fernandosavio/SOPt-539265-6333) com código rodando</sup>

É uma solução simples para um problema simplificado.

Digo simplificado pois estou assumindo que estejamos recebendo apenas caracteres dentro do range ASCII sem precisar pensar em Unicode. Por exemplo, no código acima eu posso digitar como senha `ṕṕṕṕṕṕṕṕ` que será considerado *alpha* pois `"ṕ".isalpha() == True` visto que a linguagem considera *alpha* qualquer caractere que seja marcado como *"Letter"* no banco de dados do Unicode. Se esse é o comportamento desejado ou se você quer considerar como caractere especial, vai da sua necessidade.

Então a solução acima pode ser usada como um esqueleto para o comportamento que você quer programar, mas aconselho você a ler com atenção as seguintes documentações: [`str.isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum), [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha), [`str.isascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isascii), [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal), [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) e [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric).

*PS: se você quer usar expressões regulares, o [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8674/perguntas-frequentes-que-j%c3%a1-foram-respondidas-no-sopt/8686#8686) postado nos comentários da sua pergunta é mais que o suficiente.*

---

**Dica não relacionada à solução**

Você pode usar a função [`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) ao invés da função `input()` para receber a senha do usuário. A diferença é que [`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) não mostra a senha do usuário na digitação.

Seria só trocar:

```
senha = input("Insira a senha:")
```

Por:

```
from getpass import getpass

senha = getpass("Insira a senha:")
```

Comment: Resposta muito boa, próximo ao que comentei (apesar de pensar agora que talvez minha ideia fosse muito mais elaborada sem necessidade), por dar um exemplo de "validação" melhor (com incremento) e ainda por citar o getpass(). +1

Answer (score 0):

Como o comentário do Ruan indica, a melhor forma para resolver esse problema seria Regex. Mas caso não queira seguir por esse caminho, é possível fazer algo assim:

```
digitos = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q' , 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


def temDigito(entrada):
    for letra in entrada:
        if digitos.count(letra) > 0:
            return True

    return False;

def temLetra(entrada):
    for letra in entrada:
        if letras.count(letra) > 0:
            return True
        
    return False;

def senhaValida(entrada):
    return temDigito(entrada) and temLetra(entrada)

if __name__=="__main__":
    entrada = 'senha123'
    print(senhaValida(entrada))
```

Answer (score -2):

Obrigado à todos que me ajudaram. Já era madrugada quando consegui resolver.
Essa foi a mandeira:

```
while True:
    senha = input('Digite uma senha de fácil memorização: ')

    qtde_carac_senha = len(senha)

    if (senha.isalpha() and qtde_carac_senha < 8) or (senha.isdecimal() and qtde_carac_senha < 8):
        print('Senha inválida. Escolha uma senha que tenha no mínimo 8 caracteres entre letras e números.')
    elif senha.isalnum() and qtde_carac_senha < 8:
        print('Senha inválida. Escolha uma senha que tenha no mínimo 8 caracteres entre letras e números.')
    elif senha.isalnum() and qtde_carac_senha >= 8:
        print('Senha cadastrada com sucesso.')
        break
```

Dessa forma aceita apenas seguindo os dois critérios: Maior que 8 caracteres E contendo letras e números. O "while" serviu também para passar para a próxima etapa apenas após o cadastro da senha.

Agradeço mais à todos mais uma vez!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Estou dando meu negativo pois a solução não funciona e usa de maneira equivocada as condições de `len` e `str.is_alguma_coisa`. Senhas inválidas como `12345678` e `abcdefg` passam como "Sucesso" e o algoritmo não faz nada caso não entre em nenhuma condição (não há `else`). [Exemplo](https://replit.com/@fernandosavio/ZestySufficientModule#main.py).

Comment: @fernandosavio agradeço pelo comentário. irei analisar novamente.